# Prevent a fallback href from triggering if a deep-link opened a native app

Tags: javascript, jquery, deep-linking, mobile-website

I want to have a link on my webpage that attempts to open a person's Facebook profile on the Facebook mobile app if it is installed, and if not, open it up on facebook.com.

Numerous sites and SO pages have given the following method.

```html
<a data-fb-url="fb://profile?app_scoped_user_id=myProfile" 
    href="http://www.facebook.com/myProfile">
    Go to Facebook
</a>
```

```js
$('[data-fb-url]').click(function () {
    // set a back up in case the app doesn't open
    setTimeout(() => document.location.href = this.href, 25);

    // open the app if possible
    document.location.href = $(this).attr('data-fb-url');

    // prevent the link from triggering by simply being clicked
    return false;
});
```

This does in fact open the app, but it also doesn't prevent the browser from navigating to the facebook mobile page.

#### Things I've Tried

- Longer timeout lengths.
- Adding a listener to the window's `pagehide` and `unload` events and clearing the timeout.
- Opening the app link in an iframe and waiting for the frame's `load` event to clear the timeout.
- Using `window.location` instead of `document.location.href`.

None of these have prevented the location change after the app opened.

I should probably point out I've only tried these on iOS Chrome.  These methods may have worked on other browsers, but I don't really care about them just yet.

Comment: is the document.location,href is set properly? Did it change sucessfully

Comment: No it did not.  So I guess I need a way (that might not exist) to determine if the browser succeeded in switching apps?

Comment: Have you try  event.preventDefault() to prevent default window behavior?

Comment: Yes, that was actually the first thing I tried.  It actually didn't even prevent the click event from loading the anchor's url.

Comment: Just to be sure on the behaviors: When you click the link, currently, both the app and a browser window would open?

Comment: @LoredraL Yes, the app opens, but the browser doesn't seem to notice, so then `document.location.href` is set to the fallback url.  It's possible the browser *is* noticing, but I just don't know which event to listen to.